# What is the Android permission name for Expo NOTIFICATIONS?

Tags: expo

I am using local notifications in my Expo app and request permission at run-time using `Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)`. What is the Android permission name to set this in app.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set anything in `app.json` for notifications to work.

Here is the list of other permissions, that do require an `app.json` update: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#android-permissions-equivalents-inside-appjson